# Reversing AppArmor log line to rule

Tags: security, syslog, access-control, docker

I am looking for a way to easily reverse a single line from `/var/log/syslog` reported by AppArmor for a profile in complain mode. I have seen that using `aa-genprof` that it uses what is reported to the syslog to help generate rules. For the most part I have been able to hand write my rules to allow what is needed but I am now stuck with these two lines from my syslog:

> [88529.103991] audit: type=1400 audit(1414408592.500:5298): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="mount" info="failed type match" error=-13 profile="docker-das" name="/var/lib/docker/btrfs/" pid=9289 comm="docker" srcname="/var/lib/docker/btrfs/" flags="rw, bind"
>
> [88529.104010] audit: type=1400 audit(1414408592.500:5299): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="mount" info="failed type match" error=-13 profile="docker-das" name="/var/lib/docker/btrfs/" pid=9289 comm="docker" flags="rw, private"

I have tried adding the following line (and several variants while fiddling) to my `docker-das` profile but to no avail:

```
mount fstype=btrfs -> /var/lib/docker/btrfs/
```

The only reason I can see that this wouldn't work is that `comm` is equal to `docker` as opposed to `mount` (which it is when using native mount commands).

Unfortunately I can't seem to get `aa-genprof` to be of any help (I believe due to the profile having a non standard name) and the AppArmor documentation (although helpful now I have found the right page in their wiki) is a mess.

If there is an easy way of generating the required line then that would be great knowledge to have, otherwise, can anyone see what is wrong with the rule or work out what rule I need to allow the mounts shown in the logs. What I would like is to have the strongest match for a log line so that then I can decide which parts aren't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a complete solution (it doesn't solve being able to generate a matching rule from any log line) the following is the best solution I could come up with for the specific problem and should be secure enough:

```
deny mount /dev/**,
mount -> /var/lib/docker/btrfs/
```

But it would still be nice to be able to get the strongest possible match for the log entry so that I can then use it, or make it weaker (if I wish).